# linux, установка linux-headers

Tags: linux

У меня установлена linux версии 5.4.0-kali3-amd64. Для нее просто нет linux-headers нужной версии. Что делать? Где их взять? Как их установить?

Comment: А как вы установили linux указанной версии?

Comment: Вроде это был уже установленный образ для vmwere с kali.org

Comment: Что вы видете тут `apt-cache search linux-headers`

Answer (score 1):

Cмотри версию ядра

```
uname -a
```

Доступные хидеры можно посмотреть через

```
apt-cache search linux-headers
```

Если есть нужная версия - установи

```
apt install linux-headers-ВЕРСИЯ-amd64
```

Если нет совпадений - обновляй ядро и хидеры

Актуальная версия 5.5.17-1kali1

Попробуй обновиться

```
apt update
apt install linux-image-amd64 linux-headers-amd64
apt upgrade
apt autoremove
```

Обновится вся система и будут установленны image и headers одной последней версии. Потом понадобится перезагрузится.